# For Loop : Iterating via character - Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, char

I am writing an chess app, in that, to iterate via integer I am using,

```
for(var i =0; i<8; i++) { var ch = convertToCharector(i);  //using ch here...
```

But it would be more appropriate for me, if I do like

```
for(var ch='a';ch <= 'h';ch++){ // using ch directly...
```

which **improves readablility.**

But In javascript the increment of char (in for loop ch++) is not possible, since they are not stored as integers in memory.

What Could I do to achieve this?

Whether `for(var ch='a';ch <= 'h';ch++){ // using ch directly...` way a direct way is not possible? Instead of using a third variable str="abcdefgh", then using str.

Comment: Please search before posting.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ya I did searching. `function nextChar(c) {
    return String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
}
nextChar('a');

` this will give answer. But I am already doing that only in `convertToChar`. I want a direct way if any, instead of calling a function.

Comment: Calling a function is fairly "direct".

Answer (score 2):

You can get pretty close by something like:

```
for(var ch = 'a'.charCodeAt(0); ch <= 'h'.charCodeAt(0); ch++ ) {
```

But if readability is all you're after, I don't know if the above helps. You might be better off with something like:

```
var board = { a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3, e: 4, f: 5, g: 6, h: 7 };
for(var ch = board.a; ch <= board.h; ch++) {
}
```

If you need a parser it could look something like this:

```
board.get = function(i) { return String.fromCharCode(97+i); }

...

board.get(board.a) // "a";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a string defined as:

```
chars = "abcdefgh";
```

and then point to the required character in that string:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
 canvas.drawText("" + chars.charAt(i), x, y * 30, Paint); // This draws the characters vertically
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can define global variables like this

```
var _LETTERS_='abcdefgh',
    _A_=0,
    _B_=1,
    _C_=2,
    _D_=3,
    _E_=4,
    _F_=5,
    _G_=6,
    _H_=7;
```

and use them like that...

```
for(var i=_A_;i<=_H_; i++) { var j=_LETTERS_[i];
```